# How to differentiate between reload and close in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reload, onunload

So I have a situation where a user can do a reload or close the browser tab. In both situations I want the script to take different actions. Is there a way I can differentiate between a reload, which generates an onUnload followed by an onLoad event, and closing of the tab by user (which generates an onUnload event)?

Answer (score 1):

id' recommend storing some value the browser when `onUnload` fires, so you can check for this value in the `onLoad` handler.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617250/storing-persistent-data-in-browser) for info on storing data in the browser

additionally, you might save some timestamp to check how much time has elapsed between onUnload and onLoad, making sure it's actually a 'reload'.

Comment: In my scenario, if it is a reload I needed to stop browser's action there only and not let it proceed with onUnload(which I realized cannot be done as onUnload is not cancel-able)