# I want to clear the local storage when user close the window but if it reload the window then do nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, ecmascript-6

I want to clear the local storage when user close the window but if it reload the window then do nothing I use this but it will cler the local storage when I reload the page. I use this function

```
window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', function() {
   dispatch(logout());
   dispatch(userLoggedOut());
   deleteFromLocalStorage("authToken");
   deleteFromLocalStorage("user");
   deleteFromLocalStorage("websiteMenu");
   deleteFromLocalStorage("allowedUserAction");
   navigate("/login");
});
```

Comment: Have you considered using cookies instead? Localstorage doesn't really have a concept of expiring, it is intended to persist. But you can set the cookie to only exist while the browser is in a current session. If it has to be localstorage you will find onbeforeunload is inconsistent and doesn't always fire - when force closed for example. Could you use sessionstorage instead of localstorage? This naturally expires

Comment: See these 2 questions.
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484100/how-to-differentiate-between-reload-and-close-in-javascript?rq=3
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617250/storing-persistent-data-in-browser