# Can Javascript make changes beyond the browser?

Tags: javascript, client-server

I've made a very simple to-do list. The user can enter some information, click submit and it is added to an unordered HTML list.
However, the obvious problem is that the information is not saved. On a simple browser refresh, all the information is gone.

Can Javascript save this new information next time I visit the page? (Would it be AJAX, or will I have to start learning some PHP?)

Comment: you could use cookies if its non-vital info. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm

Comment: Or HTML5 local storage, or AJAX to server-side code or 3rd-party APIs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for persisting data locally in JavaScript: cookies, localStorage, webStorage, and indexed DB. The first two are pretty much universally supported in modern browsers; the last two not quite as well supported. There's a nice article about the first three [here](http://www.webdirections.org/blog/webstorage-persistent-client-side-data-storage/). You can also consider keeping data on the server. See, e.g., [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617250/storing-persistent-data-in-browser). There are also third-party packages like [persistence.js](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs) that provide a higher-level interface to storage that can be either local or web-based.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use java script as a server side language but it's not recommended! It's not very appropriate for this operations. May be you should try to learn PHP or JSP etc.